# Arduino IDE on eOS? Java?

Tags: release-juno, ide, java

Tried to install Arduino IDE on Juno, install script gave warnings about icons not being installed on desktop (which is fine since no desktop folder for eOS) but then when try to launch the IDE icon from Applications it doesn't go. I'm guessing it's a java app? I don't want to run java on eOS unless it's already there. Any insight to running this IDE on Juno would be welcome.

Comment: I installed the Aruduino IDE on eOS with no issues.  I installed it using Synaptic.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Flatpak version of the Arduino IDE and since it comes with it's own runtime you don't have to have Java or any icons installed.

In case you need them:

[Installing flatpak on elementary OS](https://flatpak.org/setup/elementary%20OS/)

[Arduino IDE on Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/cc.arduino.arduinoide)

Answer (score 0):

you can also install fritzing. this can be used with Arduino and pi.
you will need to install the parts file also
sudo apt install fritzing && sudo apt install fritzing-parts